# How to run a countdown timer throughout the lifecycle of an app?

Tags: java, android, timer

I want to make a app where - a timer will be running throught the life-cycle of the app-Meaning: when the user opens the app for the first time-the timer will start and run until it is UNINSTALLED(it will run even when the app is close!)
Because IN MY APP I want to update a value every 1 hour, regardless of the user using the app-i.e. if the user reopens the app after the specified time interval he will see the updated variable.
Any idea how can I implement it
(I thought of countdown timer-but it stops if the app is closed! and even threads run only when the app is open)

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: 1. Service  2. Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);  used to  run at thread specific intervals (minutes,seconds,hours) your wish .whether tour app opened or not. 3. BroadcastReciever  -to start a service when mobile poweron(Boot)